# How to flip Character according to mouse position Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am using a 2D model in a 3D game and I was wondering how to horizontally flip my character according to the mouse position. eg. The mouse is pointed to the right of the character (toward an enemy or interact) and the character should face the same direction, then the player drags the mouse to the other side this should flip the character to face the mouse again (not looking directly at the mouse just looking to the side of the screen that the mouse is on).

I have a script that rotates the character's sword (this is where I use the mouse position) and another script that should use the rotation of the sword to determine which way the character faces.

(sword rotation)

```
        public void Aim()
        {
            var (success, position) = GetMousePosition();
            if (success)
            {
                // Calculate the swordDirection
                var swordDirection = position - transform.position;

                // You might want to delete this line.
                // Ignore the height difference.
                //swordDirection.x = 0;
                swordDirection.y = 0;
                //swordDirection.z = 0;

                Debug.Log(swordDirection.y);

                if (swordDirection.y >= 0)
                {
                    swordRight == true;
                }

                else if (swordDirection.y <=0.01)
                {
                    swordRight == false;
                }

                // Make the transform look in the swordDirection.
                transform.forward = swordDirection;
            }
        }
```

(character flip)

```
public class CharacterFlip : MonoBehaviour
    {
        rotateSword swordRight;

/*
        private void Awake() {
            playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
*/

        private void charDirection()
        {
            if (swordRight == true)
            {
                gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
            }

            else if (swordRight == false)
            {
                gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

However with this code I am getting this error twice on 2 different lines

```
rotateSword.cs(60,21): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

and 

rotateSword.cs(65,21): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

I know this is probably a very inefficient way of doing this and I am open to suggestions on an easier way. I was thinking just getting mouse pos again in the `Character flip` script but wasn't sure

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would try to not use the other script, and just get the mouse position in the second script - if you want to do it your way I would use `public rotateSword RS;` instead of `rotateSword swordRight;` then on the if and else statements use `rotateSword.swordRight`. After, in the editor drag the rotateSword script on the RS field.

This was not tested so may not work.

Comment: Did it end up working?